# Use Views field output as a class? Tokens?

Tags: 7, views, theming, taxonomy-terms, display-suite

I have a field in my view which displays the taxonomy vocabulary that each result/node is linked to. However, I need a way to get that taxonomy vocabulary result and use it as a class for the view row - not just the field.

Has anyone had any success with something like this before? Options I can think of might be Tokens, direct template theming, or Display Suite, but I don't know how I would go about fetching that vocabulary field output and using it as the row's class.

Any help would be received gratefully :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing replacement token to row class as shown in figure below:

[image]

**Update #1**

Install [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) & add Global: PHP field in view, then enter following values in PHP field

Value code => `return strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $row->title));`

Output Value => `<?php echo $value; ?>`

Replace [title] with [php] in Row class. Check image below for reference.

[image]

Comment: Hi Vishal; that does work! Only one problem. If the content of a [title] field is 'Hi There', then the row class also becomes 'Hi There', when I need it to be 'hi-there'. For a class I obviously need to make the output lowercase and replace the space with a dash. Any ideas?

Comment: Check Update #1 for your query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use it as a class for the whole row rather than just for the field, use a [views template](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7).

The Advanced -> OTHER -> Theme: Information section of your view usually has good ideas on what to call files but it doesn't seem to include anything for the row.

If you're using row style: fields... try making a template file called `views-view-fields--myviewname.tpl.php`.

To dig into the variables available to that template file, the first thing you want to do is install the Devel module, turn it on, and put this in the template:

```
dpm($content);
```

or maybe

```
dpm($output);
```

dpm() prints the named variable on the screen when the file is run.